# XmlIgnore not ignoring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return an object to an ajax request with an api 2 controller in an MVC 5 app. my controller looks like this:

```
public class RFQsController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDBContext db = new ApplicationDBContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public Models.RFQChecklist.RFQ GetRFQByQuote(string number)
    {
        var quote = db.QuoteSet.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Number == number);
        if(quote != null)
        {
            return quote.RFQ?.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

RFQ looks like this:

```
public class RFQ
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int QuoteID { get; set; }

    //other values

    [XmlIgnore, JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Quote.Quote Quote { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RFQ_Signoff> Signoffs { get; set; }
}
```

It's important to ignore Quote because Quote has a reference to its contained RFQs, so that would be a circular reference. So when serializing an RFQ for consumption, I'm trying to ignore Quote, because Quote has to reference RFQ. The problem is that XmlIgnore isn't... ignoring. I've also tried `ScriptIgnore`, and the combination of `DataContract`/`DataMember`. No matter what I do, the MVC 5 serializer seems to try (and fail) to serialize the `Quote` object again.
I'm quite certain it is because of this value, because if I remove `JsonIgnore` then it doesn't work when I try to retrieve as Json, but if I include it it works.

Comment: Try removing virtual

Comment: @dickrichie, still errors. Also entity framework needs the virtual.

Comment: Is your controller returning JSON or XML or both?

Comment: @mjwills it seems to do either depending on what you ask for. So if I load the page in firefox, I get an xml error object. But if I load it in internet explorer, I get valid json.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit your return data you need to use linq `select` instead of `[XmlIgnore, JsonIgnore]` attribute.

you can try to use an anonymous object to contain your expect return fields.

```
return quote.RFQ?.Select(x => new {
                        ID = x.ID,
                        QuoteID = x.QuoteID,
                        Signoffs = x.Signoffs }).FirstOrDefault();
```

instead of

```
return quote.RFQ?.FirstOrDefault();
```

---

Try to return `IHttpActionResult`

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetRFQByQuote(string number)
{
    var quote = db.QuoteSet.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Number == number);
    if(quote != null)
    {
        var result = quote.RFQ?.Select(x => new {
                            ID = x.ID,
                            QuoteID = x.QuoteID,
                            Signoffs = x.Signoffs }).FirstOrDefault()
        return Ok(result);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a different error, it can't serialize the `Signoffs`.

Comment: Bizarre, firefox now gets valid json, even though it was getting XML before. Of course, this introduces a maintenance nightmare, but it does seem to work.

Comment: @AdamR.Grey You can upvote or mark this answer if that help you :)